# Trying to acces open workbook gives 'subsript out of range'

Tags: vba, excel

I have a strange problem which I can't solve.

I have a macro in Workbook "1.xlsm". This macro is opening Workbook "2.xlsx" and is getting some data to Workbook "1.xlsm". This code work perfect on my computer but it is giving error 'subscript out of range" on computer of my friend. My OS is Win 8.1, Excel 2010, my friend Win 10, excel 2016.
Here is part of the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim i as integer
Dim Miesiac as integer
Dim TempS1 as single

Miesiac = Month(Cells(2, 9))
Workbooks.Open ("D:\2.xlsx")
i = 2
Do While Workbooks("2").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2) <> ""
    If Month(Workbooks("2").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2)) = Miesiac Then
        TempS1 = Workbooks("2").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 6) - Workbooks("2").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 5)
    EndIf
    i=i+1
Loop
Workbooks("2").Close
Cells(7, 4) = TempS1
End Sub
```

In line with 'Do While' loop I am getting mentioned error on my friend's computer while on my it is working well. Workbook "2.xlsx: IS opened on my friend's computer and I get it's name with debug.print.
One more think this code is put This_Workbook area as this macro is Workbook_Open.
Seems to me like there are some system/excel settings on my friends computer, but I didn't find which one.
EDIT: I have put runable code not just few lines.

Comment: Reading from your issue, at least from the first glance that's most likely because the file `"2.xlsx"` is not located on the D:\ drive of your friend's computer. In general the code doesn't make much sense (don't take that as an offense, please)

Comment: I didn't put all the code just the first steps that give error, so it may seem that it have no sens. The file "2.xlsx" is on drive D:\ (i've double checked that) and IT IS opened by macro, so that's not the case.

Comment: @Renea, I understood that it's the shortened version. But ideally you should strive towards producing a reproducable example. Try to create a new worksheet and focus on the error at hand. If you still can't solve it, then edit your question with the code in hand. If anything this will just confuse people.And to add to that, it's making it twice as difficult for us to tell what's wrong with it, when you said the code worked for you, but didn't on your friends computer. That genuinely means difference in test environment we have no knowledge about!

Comment: Does it still give you the error if you replace that line with: Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\2.xlsx", I know it is essentially the same but rather give it a try.

Comment: Ok, I will put more of the code (but not all as it is long and error occurs earlier) to make it runable. About the difference in test enviroment - that is what I have though, I have written OS and Office versions, that's not much but I have no clue what should I look for.

Comment: Try `Workbooks("2.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2) <> ""  `

Comment: Yeah using Workbooks ("2.xlsx") instead of Workbooks("2") works on both computers. Thank you Aneta and JvdV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you will have better luck if you store the workbook as an object rather than having to access it with a `workbooks("name")` command.

I have tested this and found it to be working on both Excel 2010 and 2016.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wb  As Excel.Workbook, _
        i   As Long
    Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\2.xlsx")
    Let i = 1
    Do Until IsEmpty(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2))
        ''  some operation
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

This drops into the edited source from as

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wb      As Excel.Workbook, _
        i       As Long, _
        Miesiac As Integer, _
        TempS1  As Single

    Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\2.xlsx")
    Let i = 2

    With wb.Sheets(1)
        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 2))
            If Month(.Cells(i, 2)) = Miesiac Then Let TempS1 = .Cells(i, 6) - .Cells(i, 5)
            Let i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
    Call wb.Close
    Let ThisWorkbook.[D7] = TempS1

End Sub
```

Comment: I have already one solution from Aneta and JvdV, but I will give a try to your solution as well and tomorrow will give a feedback.